# How to make the text bold in Python using docx within a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, docx

I have the following code and have tried to make the text in the paragraph "A" and "B" appear bold in MS Word using the following code:

```
for i in range(0, list(df.shape)[0]):
    if df.iloc[i][2] =='Y':
        b= doc.add_paragraph(df.iloc[i][0])
        b.add_run= (df.iloc[i][0])
        b.bold = True
        doc.add_paragraph("A")
        doc.add_paragraph('')
        doc.add_paragraph("B")
        a= doc.add_table(rows=5, cols=7)
        heading_cells = a.rows[0].cells
        heading_cells[1].text = 'Col 1'
        heading_cells[2].text = 'Col 2'
    else:
        doc.add_paragraph(df.iloc[i][0])
        d = doc.add_paragraph("A")
        d.add_run= ("A")
        d.bold = True
        e = doc.add_paragraph("B")
        e.add_run= ("B")
        e.bold = True
```

The code runs through but changes are not reflected in the output.

Example of output I would like

**Line 1**

**A**

**B**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
b = doc.add_paragraph()
b.add_run('A').bold = True
```

or:

```
b=doc.add_paragraph()
r=b.add_run('A')
r.bold = True
```